# React Native- Function Call hangs and cause delay in app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, button, touchableopacity

I am new to React native and I am generating a token using node-forge library. I am using this token in each API as headers. So, I need to generate this token every time when app makes a call to server but the issue is that this function takes around 5-10 seconds to make a call and my app worked like hang app for that time.

function name is **JWTToken** and I am using this function to create token.

**on button click I call API calling method**

```
const getUser = () => {
setLoader(true);

const token =  JWTToken('');

var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  username: userName.toLocaleLowerCase(),
  password: password,
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: BASE_URL + GET_USER,
  headers: {
    'x-jwt-token': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: data,
};
```

this is the code that I am calling when I click the button but when I click this no loader appears till the token not generated and meanwhile I cannot click any thing on app till the time token not generated.Please help.